# i want to share post on linkedin using python script

Tags: python, linkedin-api, socialshare

hi i want to share my post on linkedin from python script i try with many script but get authorization error "You must be authenticated to access this page."

```
import oauth2
import oauth2 as oauth, urllib
import requests
import urllib


API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
API_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'

param = {'response_type':'code', 'client_id':'xxxxxxxxxxx', 'redirect_uri':'http://localhost:8069', 'state':'987654321'}

file_one = requests.post('https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?', params = param)
print "access token info file",file_one
print "access token info file.text",file_one.text
```

it return error like " You must be authenticated to access this page" how can i do that 
i also want same in google plus also